# piping sftp ReadableStream to a file does not terminate

Tags: node.js, node-streams, ssh2-sftp

I am trying to download (get) a file from sftp server using `ssh2-sftp-client`, the program does not terminate and hangs even after the events `end, close` is triggered on the ReadableStream and the events `finish and close` are triggered on the WriteableStream. Below is the program and it's output. There are no errors as well, how do I debug? what is happening? Any help would be very much appreciated

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const fs = require("fs");
const Client = require("ssh2-sftp-client");
const util = require("util");


const sftp = new Client();
const path = require("path");
const openpgp = require("openpgp"); // use as CommonJS, AMD, ES6 module or via window.openpgp

openpgp.initWorker({
    path: "openpgp.worker.js"
}); // set the relative web worker path

const config = {
    host: 'xxxx',
    port: '1111',
    username: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxx'
};

function getFileFromSFTP() {
    console.log("Program Execution started");
    /* get files from SFTP */
    const remotePath = "remoteFile";
    const localPath = "localFile"
    sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
        sftp.get(remotePath, true, null).then((data) => {
            data.on('error', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
            data.on('end', () => {
                console.log("rs end");
            });
            data.on('close', () => {
                console.log("rs closed");
            });
            data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localPath).on('error', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            }).on('finish', () => {
                console.log("ws finish");
            }).on('close', () => {
                console.log("ws close");
            }));
        });
    });
}

function init() {
    getFileFromSFTP();
}

init();
```

## output

```
> node index.js

Program Execution started
rs end
ws finish
ws close
rs closed
```

Comment: have you tried closing the sftp connection after receiving the file from sftp server?

Comment: @R.Sarkar you are right